# Keep leading zeros when integer length is unknown

Tags: c, integer, reverse

The following program reverses user input. However, for numbers with trailing zeroes, the zeroes are 'ignored' when printing the reversed number.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int n, reversedNumber = 0, remainder;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while(n != 0)
    {
        remainder = n%10;
        reversedNumber = reversedNumber*10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }

    printf("Reversed Number = %d\n", reversedNumber);

    return 0; 
}
```

Since the **integer length of the user input is unknown**, how can we print all the trailing zeros for example:

```bash
Enter an Integer: 3000 
Reversed Number = 0003
```

Comment: Read it as a string and reverse the string.

Comment: I had done that earlier, maybe I need to add some context to the question. The goal is to add the digits of the original number starting from the second-to-last digit of the original number. That means converting the *string* back to an integer will lose the leading zeros. @AndrewHenle

Comment: @daumie So, you asked how to do something, but that's not your actual question? You need to clarify *exactly* what you want to know. The answer alk provided precisely answers the the question asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> integer length is unknown

It isn't. :-)

Count the number of iterations and pass it to the final call to `printf` as width.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int n, reversedNumber = 0, remainder;

   printf("Enter an integer: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   {
     size_t i = (0 > n);

     while (n != 0)
     {
       remainder = n % 10;
       reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + remainder;
       n /= 10;
       ++i;
     }

     printf("Reversed Number = %0*d\n", (int) i, reversedNumber); /* Alternatively
                                            to the cast you can define i as int. */
   }

   return 0; 
}
```

From [the documentation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p4):

> **4** Each conversion specification is introduced by the character %. After the %, the following appear in sequence:
>
> [...]
>
> - An optional minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces (by default) on the left (or right, if the left adjustment flag, described later, has been given) to the field width. The field width takes the form of an asterisk * (described later) or a nonnegative decimal integer.[...])
>
> [...]
>
> **5** As noted above, a field width [...] may be indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an int argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments specifying field width [...] shall appear (in that order) before the argument (if any) to be converted.
>
> [...]

Comment: Getting:
warning: field width should have type 'int', but argument has type
      'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat]

And also, I noted that an extra zero is added e.g 3000 is reversed to 00003.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I corrected and annotated to code.

Comment: See my fix for negative numbers.

Comment: Great! I had overlooked negative numbers. works as expected now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the integer length of the user input is unknown, how can we print all the trailing zeros?

The integer text length *can* be known.  Use `"%n"` to record the offset of the scan up to that point.

---

To reverse a string numerically (obviously a simple textual reversal is possible), record the length of the input.

When printing, insure leading zeros are pre-pended as needed using `"%0*u"`.

```
int main(void) {
  int start, end;
  unsigned n;        // I prefer unsigned here, but could use int and %d below.
  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  //         v--- Consume leading white-space
  if (scanf(" %n%u%n", &start, &n, &end) == 1) {
    int length = end - start;
    unsigned reversedNumber = 0;
    for (int i = length; i > 0; i--) {
      unsigned remainder = n % 10;
      reversedNumber = reversedNumber * 10 + remainder;
      n /= 10;
    }
    printf("Reversed Number = %0*u\n", length, reversedNumber);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Sample run

```
Enter an integer: 00123000
Reversed Number = 00032100
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use char array(string) for this because , its general mathematics rule **we didn't consider zeros on left**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char value[]="3000";
    printf(" Number : %s ",value);
    char *rev=strrev(value);
    printf("Reversed Number = %s ",rev);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strrev()` isn't C, but some vendor specific extension.